# Сомневаюсь: нужна ли запятая в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*Не знаю(,) можно ли уже тебе сказать.*
Или:
*Не знаю(,) можно ли уже тебе сказать?*

(Пояснение: автор вопроса **НЕ** определил **знак** в конце предложения.)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна. Это сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, которое присоединяется к главному при помощи союза ЛИ. Вопросительный знак в таком предложении чаще всего не ставится, вопросительной интонации нет, но он возможен при наличии прямого вопроса.

**Союз ли, употребляемый после знаменательного слова, указывает на предположение с оттенком неуверенности и раскрывает содержание косвенного или прямого вопроса. Союз ли ставится в придаточной части не в начале, а после первого слова.**

*Например: Неизвестно (что?), был ли он дома. Вы спрашиваете, знал ли я Шмидта до его речи на кладбище? Нет, не знал (Пауст.); Не знаю, походил ли водопад на зверя, но он действительно был красив (Чак.).*[СПП с придаточными изъяснительными](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/295-slo)

***Не знаю, можно ли уже тебе сказать.***